# Ruby if statement to exclude multiple string variations

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to parse an array that I've created to ultimately write the 'good' values to a file.  The array may look something like this, however the contents may change, so I can't match for a certain value:

```
array = ["10.10.10.0/24", "10.10.10.1/32", "10.10.10.129/32", "127.0.0.0/8", "169.254.0.0/16", "192.168.1.0/24", "255.255.255.255/32"]
```

I believe that it makes sense to check the array values **before** writing to the file and **not write** the values I know that I don't want.  In this case, the values would always be:

```
 10.10.10.1/32
 10.10.10.129/32
 127.0.0.0/8
 169.254.0.0/16
 255.255.255.255/32
```

My initial `if` statement looked like this, which *sort of* accomplished what I am after, but not completely:

```
 if !network.include?("/32" || "127.0.0.0/8" || "169.254.0.0/16" || "255.255.255.255/32")
   file.write("#{network}\n")
 end
```

Which results in (lines 2 & 3 shouldn't have been included):

```
 10.10.10.0/24
 127.0.0.0/8
 169.254.0.0/16
 192.168.1.0/24
```

What have I done wrong?  Is there a better way to perform the lookup/matching/exclusion?

Comment: Not clear what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
networks = ["10.10.10.0/24", "10.10.10.1/32", "10.10.10.129/32", "127.0.0.0/8", "169.254.0.0/16", "192.168.1.0/24", "255.255.255.255/32"] 
banned_networks = [/\/32/, "127.0.0.0/8", "169.254.0.0/16", "255.255.255.255/32"]

networks.reject do |e|
  case e
  when *banned_networks
    true
  end
end.each {|network| file.write("#{network}\n")}
```

Comment: Awesome!  Just had to make a small edit to the when statement line to make the regex work.  Thanks!

Comment: @Godzilla74 yeah. Spotted this too. Will add some extra in few seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use "or" `||` like that.

Better might be...

```
exclude_entries = [ '/32', 
                    '127.0.0.0/8',
                    '169.254.0.0/16',
                    '255.255.255.255/32'
                  ]
match_pattern = Regex.new(exclude_entries.join('|'))

(array.reject{|n| n =~ match_pattern}.each do |network|
     file.write("#{network}\n")
end
```

The problem is that the expression `"/32" || "127.0.0.0/8"` *always* returns "/32" ... the "or" just returns the first "truthy" value and "/32" is "truthy"

Edited to use regular expression so as to exclude partial text.

Comment: What would be the way to place certain unknowns into the exclude_entries array?  For instance, `/32`, which you'll notice there are a few addresses that end in `/32`.

Comment: Hi, ok, edited so exclude entries can include one or more partials.

Comment: Ruby 2.3 implements [`Enumerable#grep_v`](http://ruby-doc.org/cor/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep_v) which can be used here instead of `#reject`: `array.grep_v(match_pattern)`.